# How to add resources to non qt-project in qt-creator using qmake

Tags: qt-creator, sfml

As the title says I'm trying to add resources to a project (SFML) that I'm developing on GNU/Linux. I'm using Qt-creator to develop it as a non-qt application using qmake to build the project. This means that the usual Qt way to handle resources in a `.qrc` is not an option.

I've tried to symlink my resource folder into the build folder which works but this obviously feels wrong.

Any suggestions would be of great help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After smashing my head against this for a while I ended up restructuring my project and using make instead of qmake. That worked like a charm.

Then I just added my custom make script to the build steps in Qt Creator so that I can build and run with ctrl+r.